# Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteData)?

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking to post an audio with some data. I am getting following exception.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteData)'
```

I am using this code..

```
dict=@{@"access_token":[defaults valueForKey:@"TOKEN"],@"email":email,@"prayer":passData};

if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dict]) {
        NSLog(@"Proper JSON Object");

    }
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData  timeoutInterval:10];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
 AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
    [op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {}
```

I need to post values in this format

```
{
    "access_token" = 2cf0d8a66654fa4f;
    email = "";
    prayer =     {
        audio = <63616666 00010000 64657363 00000000 00000020 40e58880 00000000 696d6134 00000000 00000044 00000040 00000002 00000000 6b756b69 00000000 00000000 66726565 0000000>
 98903013 31faae9c bb7b0780 80808080>;
        "category_id" = "";
        description = "";
        "expired_date" = "Expiration Date";
        "is_audio" = 1;
        "is_urgent" = 0;
        "prayer_access_id" = "";
        "prayer_type_id" = 1;
        subject = "";
    };
}
```

I don't know why this is happening, I have posted values before with this format but when I try to post audio as data, I am getting this exception.
Thanks in advance

**Edit**

Here i am making data

```
 NSData *audioFile=[self audioData];
 if (audioFile==nil) {
        [passData setObject:@"" forKey:@"audio"];
        [passData setObject:@"0" forKey:@"is_audio"];

    }else{

        [passData setObject:audioFile forKey:@"audio"];
        [passData setObject:@"1" forKey:@"is_audio"];
    }


-(NSData *)audioData{
    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                            NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"recordTest.caf"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    NSData *audioData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    return audioData;
}
```

this what i am inserting audio file

Comment: show that passData initialization.

Comment: @Shoaib thanks for replay i have initlized in viewdidload method

postData=[NSDictionary dictionary];
    passData=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

Comment: What is the data type of that audio key in the passData dictionary? Actually, I want to see what type of data you have inserted in your dictionary.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html

Comment: @Shoaib do i need to any basecode64 format for audio.i am just sending NSData not any conversion

Comment: Yes! you'll need to convert NSData to base64EncodedString.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot put `NSData` in JSON. The `audio` is `NSData`. As the `NSJSONSerialization` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html) says:

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following properties:
>
> - The top level object is an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.
> - All objects are instances of `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, or `NSNull`.
> - All dictionary keys are instances of `NSString`.
> - Numbers are not `NaN` or infinity.

If you want to include `NSData` in JSON, you have to convert it to a string. The common way to do that is to base64 encode it (and then, in the destination, decode the base64 string).

Comment: FWIW, Swift's [`JSONEncoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder) allows a [`dataEncodingStrategy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder/2895381-dataencodingstrategy) and defaults to `.base64`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your Json text. check it on http://www.jsoneditoronline.org and try again when you are sure if it is correct formed Json

Comment: thanks for comment,i am not problem with making json format,i think problem with audio data while forming json,so i need to do base encoding audio data.thanks for useful  link